# File Processing :Have issues while File proceesing in wso2

Tags: wso2

Respected Sir,

I have to process only the files which are coming to the folder newly ( there could be files which are already existing in the folder which should not be picked for processing )

The client does not want to move the files to another folder after processing. So if the file remains in the same folder after processing. They should not be re-processed and should remain in the same folder with same extension

Below is the code I am trying.  But I am not able to achieve above .Please guide.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name`enter code here`="FlatFileProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value=""/>
            <property action="remove" name="ClientApiNonBlocking" scope="axis2"/>
            <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/xmlToCsv1.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/xmlToCsv1_inputSchema.json" inputType="XML" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/xmlToCsv1_outputSchema.json" outputType="CSV"/>
            <property expression="fn:concat(fn:substring-after(get-property('MessageID'), 'urn:uuid:'), '.csv')" name="transport.vfs.ReplyFileName" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/csv"/>
            <property action="remove" name="LAST_MODIFIED" scope="transport"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="vfs:file:///C:/Flatfile/output"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.Streaming">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">50ms</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///C:/Flatfile/input1</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///C:/Flatfile/failure</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*\.xml</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.Locking">disable</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///C:/Flatfile/orgFilesProcessedSuccessfully</parameter>
</proxy>
```

With Regards,
Aditya

Answer (score 0):

With vfs Transport you have the option to use transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess NONE. But then you'll have to find a way in your inSequence to find a way to not process file that was already processed (maybe based on file date with get-property('transport', 'LAST_MODIFIED')).
Take care on the sorting in this case to process the last file first (transport.vfs.FileSortAttribute = Lastmodifiedtimestamp and transport.vfs.FileSortAsscending = false)